# How to set maxheight of a combination in ConTeXt?

Tags: context

I want to do a combination that fits in my page without taking care of figures dimensions itself. I tried this:

```
\placefigure[][myfigure]
    {mycaption}
    {\startcombination[1*4, height=0.8\textheight]
        {\externalfigure[fig1]}
        {a)}
        {\externalfigure[fig2]}
        {b)}
        {\externalfigure[fig3]}
        {c)}
        {\externalfigure[fig4]}
        {d)}
    \stopcombination
    }
```

But figures are still to big do not fit into the page.